# Equality for the sines of the angles of a triangle.

Tags: trigonometry

I wonder what would be an equality satisfied by the sines of the angles of a triangle.  I have seen other equalities, but they involve also some cosines.

Comment: Do you mean the sine law ? $$\frac{a}{\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{b}{\sin(\beta)}=\frac{c}{\sin(\gamma)}$$

Comment: @Peter: no, that would involve $R$ I suppose

Comment: So you mean an equation ONLY containing sines of the angles ?

Comment: @Peter: yes indeed, only the sines

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\text{If } & \alpha+\beta+\gamma = \pi \text{ radians} = 180^\circ = \text{half-circle} \\[4pt]
& \text{then } \sin(2\alpha)+\sin(2\beta) +\sin(2\gamma) = 4\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma.
\end{align}

Comment: I see.. but I would like one with only the sines of the angles, if possible

Comment: @orangeskid $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin\gamma$

Comment: @Raffaele: right... but it should be only between $\sin \alpha$, $\sin \beta$ , $\sin \gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ratio $\sin\alpha:\sin\beta:\sin\gamma$ is the same as the ratio $a:b:c,$ where $a,b,c$ are respectively the lengths of the sides opposite the angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ the only relationship that can be true of all triangles is this triangle inequality:
\begin{align}
\sin\alpha+\sin\beta & \ge \sin\gamma, \\ \sin\alpha+\sin\gamma, & \ge \sin \beta \\ \sin\beta+\sin\gamma, & \ge \sin\alpha.
\end{align}

Comment: You are right, I guess that would be the only homogenous relationship that can be had for the sines. But what of non-homogenous?